# SailsJS V1 - Blueprint query not working correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I'm trying to create a blueprint query for a sailsjs v1 model.

The model is a BlogPost which has 2 "options". One is the target and the other one is Status.

If the target is Site and the status is Published, the query should return, otherwise nope. I'm using the default REST routes provided by Sails (blueprints) and everything works fine if I try to find all of them. However, if I try to find one by ID...I can't even get back those that have a status of 'Unpublished'.

This is my code in `blueprint.js parseBlueprintOptions` ->

```
parseBlueprintOptions: function (req) {

    var queryOptions = req._sails.hooks.blueprints.parseBlueprintOptions(req);
    if (queryOptions.using === 'blogpost') {
      if (req.options.blueprintAction === 'create') {
        queryOptions.newRecord.user_id = req.session.user.id;
        return queryOptions;
      } else if (req.options.blueprintAction === 'update') {
        queryOptions.criteria.where.user_id = req.session.user.id;
        queryOptions.valuesToSet.user_id = req.session.user.id;
        return queryOptions;
      } else {
        if (req.session.administrator) {
          return queryOptions;
        } else {
          queryOptions.criteria.where.blogpost_target = 'Site';
          queryOptions.criteria.where.blogpost_status = 'Published';

          console.log(queryOptions);
          return queryOptions;
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Any tips on why the query does not get triggered for `findOne`? As i said, it returns regardless of the status/target.

Comment: Does this show any error message or do the request at all?

Comment: No error. I posted on their github and apparently ``findOne`` only supports ID's. I'll probably look for another way or override the default controller action.

Answer (score 0):

Hey 'find' returns **object** **array** and 'findone' returns only an **object**. I guess therefor it won't work!